# matrix determinant differentiation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, determinants

I am interested in computing the derivative of a matrix determinant using TensorFlow. I can see from experimentation that TensorFlow has not implemented a method of differentiating through a determinant:

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'MatrixDeterminant' 
(op type: MatrixDeterminant)
```

A little further investigation revealed that it is actually possible to compute the derivative; see for example [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula). I determined that in order to implement this means of differentiating through a determinant that I need to use the function decorator,

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("MatrixDeterminant")
def _sub_grad(op, grad):
    ...
```

However, I am not familiar enough with tensor flow to understand how this can be accomplished. Does anyone have any insight on this matter?

Here's an example where I run into this issue:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=[1]))
y = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=[1]))

A = tf.reshape(
    tf.pack([tf.sin(x), tf.zeros([1, ]), tf.zeros([1, ]), tf.cos(y)]), (2,2)
)
loss = tf.square(tf.matrix_determinant(A))


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


for step in xrange(100):
    sess.run(train)
    print sess.run(x)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check "Implement Gradient in Python" section [here](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#implement-the-gradient-in-python)

In particular, you can implement it as follows

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("MatrixDeterminant")
def _MatrixDeterminantGrad(op, grad):
  """Gradient for MatrixDeterminant. Use formula from 2.2.4 from
  An extended collection of matrix derivative results for forward and reverse
  mode algorithmic differentiation by Mike Giles
  -- http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1079/1/NA-08-01.pdf
"""
  A = op.inputs[0]
  C = op.outputs[0]
  Ainv = tf.matrix_inverse(A)
  return grad*C*tf.transpose(Ainv)
```

Then a simple training loop to check that it works:

```
a0 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).astype(np.float32)
a = tf.Variable(a0)
b = tf.square(tf.matrix_determinant(a))
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init_op.run()

minimization_steps = 50
learning_rate = 0.001
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(b)

losses = []
for i in range(minimization_steps):
  train_op.run()
  losses.append(b.eval())
```

Then you can visualize your loss over time

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ylabel("Determinant Squared")
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.plot(losses)
```

Should see something like this
[image: Loss plot]

Comment: Very cool! for some reason the docs on tf are causing issues.  eg:  from the links above http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.md#AUTOGENERATED-implement-the-gradient-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with what is a **derivative of a matrix determinant**.

Matrix determinant is a function which is calculated over the elements of the matrix by some formula. So if all the elements of the matrix are numbers, you the determinant will you you just one number and the derivative will be `0`. When some of the elements are variables, you will get an expression of these variables. For example:

```
x, x^2
1, sin(x)
```

The determinant will be `x*sin(x) - x^2` and the derivative is `2x + sin(x) + x*cos(x)`. The Jacobi formula just connects the determinant with adjunct matrix.

---

In your example your matrix `A` consists of only numbers and therefore the determinant is just a number and the `loss` is just a number as well. `GradientDescentOptimizer` needs to have some free variables to minimize and does not have any because your `loss` is just a number.

Comment: The real problem here is that MatrixDeterminant class does not provide a registered gradient.

Comment: @user1936768 yes this is a reason why you got the error in your python problem, but this is not a real reason. Assume the gradient method exists. It will always return you 0 no matter what. Will this be any help in your 100 iterations? How exactly will it minimize anything?

Comment: No the gradient will not be zero. I am minimizing with respect to x and y, and the matrix depends on x and y through sin and cos respectively.

Comment: @user1936768 look carefully at your example. `x` and `y` are matrices which consist of only numbers.

Comment: This isn't how TensorFlow works. Notice the Variable wrapper around x and y. Consider that if I make `loss = tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(tf.matrix_inverse(A)))` then I will indeed iterate towards an optimal solution `x = 1.57079494,  y = 1.09198811e-18` which is not what I initialized `x` or `y` to.

Comment: At any rate, this is beside the point. My example was only an example. It is easy to imagine (more) situations where the matrix depends on variables. In these cases, the fact that MatrixDeterminant does not have a gradient presents a problem.

Comment: @Salvador, you're miss-understanding this. There is a method to calculate the determinant, a number, from the numbers in the input matrix. We're talking about the derivative of the determinant *operation* with respect to each element of the input matrix, evaluated at the current value of the input. What is the derivative of `x**2` when `x=5`?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I discovered the solution that works on my problems:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("MatrixDeterminant")
def _MatrixDeterminant(op, grad):
    """Gradient for MatrixDeterminant."""
    return op.outputs[0] * tf.transpose(tf.matrix_inverse(op.inputs[0]))
```

Comment: that doesn't backprop correctly if you have something on top of determinant (ie, if you minimize determinant squared)