# Calculate log of determinant in TensorFlow when determinant overflows/underflows

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, gradient, linear-algebra, determinants

My cost function involves the calculation of log(det(A)) (assuming the det(A) is positive so the log makes sense, but A is not Hermitian so that the Cholesky decomposition is not applicable here). When det(A) is very large/small, a direct call to det(A) will overflow/underflow. To circumvent this, one use the mathematical fact that

> log(det(A)) = Tr(log(A)),

where the later can be evaluated using LU decomposition (which is more efficient than eigenvalue/SVD). This algorithm has been implemented in numpy as [numpy.linalg.slogdet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html), so the problem is how to call numpy from TensorFlow.

---

Here is what I tried

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import function

def logdet_np(a):
    _, l = np.linalg.slogdet(a)
    return l

def logdet1(a):
    return tf.py_func(logdet_np, [a], tf.float64)

@function.Defun(tf.float64, func_name='LogDet')
def logdet2(a):
    return tf.py_func(logdet_np, [a], tf.float64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant(np.eye(500)*10.)
    #print(sess.run(logdet1(a)))
    print(sess.run(logdet2(a)))
```

I first define a python function to pass out the numpy result. Then I defined two `logdet` functions using `tf.py_func`. The second function is decorated by `function.Defun` which is used to define TensorFlow functions and their gradients later. As I test them, I found that the first function `logdet1` works and gives the correct result. But the second function `logdet2` returns a KeyError.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py in __call__(self, token, args)
     77   def __call__(self, token, args):
     78     """Calls the registered function for `token` with args."""
---> 79     func = self._funcs[token]
     80     if func is None:
     81       raise ValueError("callback %s is not found" % token)

KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
```

My question is what is wrong with the `Defun` decorator? Why is it conflicting with `py_func`? How can I wrap numpy functions in TensorFlor correctly?

---

The remaining part of defining the gradient for `logdet` is related to the question [matrix determinant differentiation in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714832/matrix-determinant-differentiation-in-tensorflow). According to the solution in that question, one attempts to write

```
@function.Defun(tf.float64, tf.float64, func_name='LogDet_Gradient')
def logdet_grad(a, grad):
    a_adj_inv = tf.matrix_inverse(a, adjoint=True)
    out_shape = tf.concat([tf.shape(a)[:-2], [1, 1]], axis=0)
    return tf.reshape(grad, out_shape) * a_adj_inv
@function.Defun(tf.float64, func_name='LogDet', grad_func=logdet_grad)
def logdet(a):
    return tf.py_func(logdet_np, [a], tf.float64, stateful=False, name='LogDet')
```

The above code would work if one can solve the conflict between `Defun` and `py_func`, which is the key question that I raised above.

Comment: You can use SVD and get determinant from singular values

Comment: Is A special ( eg positive definite) ?

Comment: @dmuir det(A) is positive, but the eigenvalues are not all positive (meaning there are negative eigenvalues appearing in pairs).

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov but do you know what is the status of implementing gradient for SVD?

Comment: Divide the matrix by its largest absolute value.

Comment: This is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714832/matrix-determinant-differentiation-in-tensorflow

Comment: @wontonimo I am aware of that question, please see my updated question. There is a conflict between Defun and py_func that prevents me from implementing the method in the related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @MaxB, here I post the code to define the function `logdet` for log(abs(det(A))) and its gradient.

- `logdet` calls the numpy function [numpy.linalg.slogdet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html) to compute the log of the determinant using the idea of log(det(A))=Tr(log(A)), which is robust against the overflow/underflow of the determinant. It is based on the LU decomposition, which is more efficient compared to the eigenvalue/SVD based method.
- The numpy function `slogdet` returns a tuple containing both the sign of the determinant and the log(abs(det(A))). The sign will be neglected, since it will not contribute to the gradient signal in the optimization.
- The gradient of `logdet` is computed by matrix inversion, according to grad log(det(A)) = inv(A)^T. It is based on TensorFlow's code on [_MatrixDeterminantGrad](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg_grad.py) with slight modifications.

---

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# from https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342
# Define custom py_func which takes also a grad op as argument:
def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):
    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))
    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)
# from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg_grad.py
# Gradient for logdet
def logdet_grad(op, grad):
    a = op.inputs[0]
    a_adj_inv = tf.matrix_inverse(a, adjoint=True)
    out_shape = tf.concat([tf.shape(a)[:-2], [1, 1]], axis=0)
    return tf.reshape(grad, out_shape) * a_adj_inv
# define logdet by calling numpy.linalg.slogdet
def logdet(a, name = None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, 'LogDet', [a]) as name:
        res = py_func(lambda a: np.linalg.slogdet(a)[1], 
                      [a], 
                      tf.float64, 
                      name=name, 
                      grad=logdet_grad) # set the gradient
        return res
```

One can test that `logdet` works for very large/small determinant and its gradient is also correct.

```
i = tf.constant(np.eye(500))
x = tf.Variable(np.array([10.]))
y = logdet(x*i)
dy = tf.gradients(y, [x])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([y, dy]))
```

Result: `[1151.2925464970251, [array([ 50.])]]`

Comment: In your question, you never stated that CPU-only was OK (Otherwise calling NP can be bad). You also never stated that performance for this particular op was crucial (Otherwise, the simplest solution is best).

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the overflow, you can combat it with simple math. 
[image]

So you just need to get the eigenvalues, log them and sum them up.

Comment: TF doesn't have general eigenvalue op (nor would they be real). Using SVD is the right approach (as suggested).

Comment: @MaxB the fact that eigenvalue can be imaginary does not break the math. You still can log imaginary numbers and clearly you can sum up a few imaginary numbers. Regarding not-having eigenvalues, I am not aware of this, but what stops a person to implement own C++ functions to do this?. Now I see the comment about SVD, and if you think that this comment is enough to understand what to do - please explain us the connection between SVD and determinant.

Comment: Wrote up as an answer, since you insisted.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Thanks. I am aware of the math you mentioned. I found that eigenvalue decomposition is much slower than LU decomposition. In fact, an implementation of this Tr(log(A)) approach is already there in numpy. The problem is how to call numpy in TensorFlow. I would appreciate if you can take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVD to decompose `A`:

```
A = U S V'
```

Since the determinant of a product is a product of determinants, and the determinants of `U` and `V'` are 1 or -1, while the determinant of `S` is non-negative,

```
abs(det(A)) = det(S)
```

Therefore, log of a (positive) determinant can be computed as

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(svd(A, compute_uv=False)))
```

---

---

As of TF1.1, `tf.svd` lacks gradient (future versions will probably have it), and so I suggest adopting the implementation from *kofd*'s code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6503

Comment: The lack of gradient for SVD can be circumvented by the fact that grad of log(det(A)) is the transpose of inv(A). I have actually tested your code, it is very slow due to the SVD, much slower than `tf.log(tf.matrix_determinant(A))`. I also found that numpy provides a function `slogdet` for my purpose which is based on the more efficient LU decomposition. Now I would like to know how to call numpy form TensorFlow. Please take a look at my updated question. I would appreciate your patients a lot.

Comment: @EverettYou You can call NP from TF: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839431/tensorflow-how-to-replace-or-modify-gradient/43930598#43930598

Comment: @EverettYou or rather https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342 -- the last comment there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these references. They are very useful.